# Is there any software to automatically change or save the resolutions for my 22" and 19" monitors when playing the same game?

Tags: windows-vista, resolution

Everytime I switch to primary monitor which is 22" then I must select resolution to 1920x1080 again when first starting the same game on 19" secondary monitor with 1280x1024 resolution.

Is there any software (or can I do it with DisplayFusion multi-monitor program) to automatically change or save the resolutions for my 22" and 19" monitors when playing the same game on Windows Vista x64 Ultimate?

Comment: Automatically?  No.  It depends on how you set the resolution in the game.  Some games use configuration files stored in plain-text, in which case it's trivial to modify the file to start the game with the proper resolution.  Other games store settings in binary or encoded formats, which are more difficult (albeit not impossible) to modify.  Finally, some games use the Windows registry to store settings.  You can write a batchfile to switch configuration sets, or need to intercept the game after it starts, determine the pixel location, then close the game, swap configurations, and restart it.

Comment: is it possible with UltraMon?

Comment: Simply adjust your game to not go full screen.  Then it won't screw with you resolution